# how to subclass an ExtJS proxy - using MVC?

Tags: extjs

i have defined my proxy subclass using Ext.define and then referenced it in my Model by including my custom type in the proxy config:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields : ['first','last'],
  proxy : {
    type : 'customProxy'
  }
}
```

when ExtJS tries to load the proxy class it looks for `'proxy/cusomProxy'` instead of `'app/proxy/customProxy'` the way i would expect it to.  shouldnt subclassed proxies be stored in an app.proxy folder?

(btw, why does the proxy use 'type' instead of 'xtype' to declare is class?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting proxy configuration (not declaration!) into the store class. And you can just use something like:

```
this.proxy = Ext.create('My.new.Prpxy', {
})
```

Comment: ok, this is actually working for me.  thats good ;) i am doing this int the MODEL config, not the STORE config.  any reason why not?  also, i still dont understand why i cant use the "type" attribute of the config to "lazy" instantiate the proxy